# best way to connect android phone to the genymotion emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, genymotion

Since off yesterday I'm using Genymotion as Android emulator.

Now I'm running a server on the emulator that listens to connections.

I'm running the client on my real phone on the wireless network.

My client has IP 192.168.0.196 ip address and my emulator has 192.168.56.101 as Ip address.
I also tried the 10.0.3.15 as ip address but that doesn't matter.

Whats the best way to connect my phone to the genymotion emulator?

Thought changing some settings in the virtual box but everytime when genymotion starts the settings are back to default :-).

Answer (score 2):

Change the second network interface in VirtualBox to "bridged". This should enable Genymotion to automatically obtain an address in your local network (you need a DHCP server)